# Modify flowfile with timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi

I have video data coming from device to Apache-nifi processor, i want to add time stamp to this flow file and store in Kafka using put Kafka processor. what is the best way to that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor and use the Expression Language expression `${now():toNumber()}` to express the current time as milliseconds and add this as an attribute to the flowfile. You can then route to `PutKafka`.

Comment: In addition to what Andy said, I would just like to mention that as far as I know, Kafka does not have header attributes on each message, so the only way to pass the timestamp + video to kafka, would be to put the timestamp into the payload which then makes it not a valid video anymore.